# Change directory writable in windows using python

Tags: python, windows

In windows, the directories inside the C drive can be changed into writable manually by editing the security attributes of a directory providing full control to the user.
How this can be done in Python?

My thinking was:

```
import os, stat
my_dir = 'C:\\Program Files\\Java'
os.chmod (my_dir, stat.S_IWRITE)
```

But no success.

Do anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
os.chmod(my_dir,0o777) # read and write by everyone
os.chmod(my_dir,0o755)  # read and write by me, readable for everone else
```

[Python chmod documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod)

Note Although Windows supports chmod(), you can only set the file’s read-only flag with it (via the stat.S_IWRITE and stat.S_IREAD constants or a corresponding integer value). All other bits are ignored.

Comment: 0 is zero and o is last alphabet of zero? @Adem Öztaş

Comment: @ Adem Öztaş still the access is denied, os.chmod(my_dir,0o777) did not work

Comment: Because, you are not owner 'C:\\Program Files\\Java' ?

Comment: i have logged into Windows7 as an administrator @Adem Öztaş